# How to fix canvas size in child component in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, vue.js, html5-canvas

I try to create compare images (img and canvas) in a child component.
It fails, when I pass created img as a prop from main component to child, I take width and height from my image prop and then apply it to my canvas with HTML element (all sizes works well), but at the end the Canvas has a cropped image and in Dom Elements(HTML) I don't see added sizes in canvas element.

Here is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jzrz0r95vw)